# plugin bxslider disable touch swipe top bottom

Tags: iphone, slider, touch, device, swipe

I use a bxlslider and in mobile, a have a probelem with touch event,
Is it possible to disable the vertical touch events so it only works when the scroll is swiped horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been asked and discussed numerous times,

here: [Horizontal swipe gesture and vertical page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709577/horizontal-swipe-gesture-and-vertical-page-scroll)

here: [bxSlider touch enabled - disable vertical touch events so only horizontal touch events work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460057/bxslider-touch-enabled-disable-vertical-touch-events-so-only-horizontal-touch)

here: [ios6 touch event handling javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701463/ios6-touch-event-handling-javascript)

and here: [BX Slider and scrolling the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845799/bx-slider-and-scrolling-the-page)